# Call method on undeploy from a Java web-application

Tags: servlets, jboss, web.xml

I am developing a Java web-application. The application connects to a Lucene index. I create a singleton instance of IndexSearcher. This instance opens some files. When I redeploy the web-application, the files opened by the earlier instance of IndexSearcher continue to remain open, and another instance is created by the redeployed application. After a few redeploys, the system starts throwing a "too many open files" exception. I would like to close the old instance before redeploying, so that the old files are closed, but I cannot figure out how to do that? Is there a directive in web.xml that's called upon un-deploy, similar to load-on-startup? I'm running the web-application on a jboss server.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Implement a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

```
@WebListener
public class LuceneConfig implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do your job here during webapp startup.
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do your job here during webapp shutdown.
    }

}
```

If you're not on Servlet 3.0 yet (which is already out for 2 years though), then you need to remove the `@WebListener` annotation and register it manually in `web.xml` as follows:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.LuceneConfig</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: It works here without registering it. Using Mojarra 2.3.3 on Payara 4.1 (173 build).

Comment: Sure it will work fine. Payara 4.x is Servlet 3.1 based. Then the `@WebListener` will work just fine. As answered, it won't work when you're not on Servlet 3.0 yet. The JSF impl/version is irrelevant as it doesn't play a role here. Only the Servlet version is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

If you implement `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` and register that class in `web.xml` as a  `<listener>`, then then `contextDestroyed()` method will be called before the context is unloaded.