# Thread Problems with Web Application and Directory Watcher using Spring and Apache Commons IO

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, apache-commons-io

I'm developing a web application using Spring Framework 4.2 with Apache Tomcat 8.5. When I modify a file in a directory, I need to call a method in a bean object in order to reload the information.
I work with Apache Commons IO to watch the directory, however when I undeploy the application, the thread which scan the directory still lives.

This is the code to watch the changes

```
    final File directory = new File(groupsDirectory);
    FileAlterationObserver fao = new FileAlterationObserver(directory);
    fao.addListener(new FileAlterationListenerImpl());
    final FileAlterationMonitor monitor = new FileAlterationMonitor(pollingInterval);
    monitor.addObserver(fao);
    monitor.start();
```

And this the message that Tomcat shows me when I undeploy the webapplication:

> 22-May-2016 19:13:14.377 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-12] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [Argo] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-12] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
>    java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
>    org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationMonitor.run(FileAlterationMonitor.java:188)
>    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is Implement a ServletContextListener as described in this post: [Call method on undeploy from a Java web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184835/call-method-on-undeploy-from-a-java-web-application)

Then you should be able to stop the monitor in the `contextDestroyed()` method of your `ServletContextListener`.

I would recommend having a Factory object that holds onto the **static** monitor instance, then you can make calls to the Factory and not have the `ServletContextListener` deal with the monitor directly.

The Factory would persist for the life of the classloader (e.g. the duration of the webapp being started)

Answer (score 0):

I just used the annotation @PreDestroy to stop the monitor before the applications stops.

```
@Component
public class GroupsMonitor {

    private final FileAlterationMonitor monitor;

    @Autowired
    public GroupsMonitor(@Value("${groups.directory}") String groupsDirectory,
            @Value("${groups.intervalMonitor}") long pollingInterval) throws Exception {
        final File directory = new File(groupsDirectory);
        FileAlterationObserver fao = new FileAlterationObserver(directory);
        fao.addListener(new FileAlterationListenerImpl());
        monitor = new FileAlterationMonitor(pollingInterval);
        monitor.addObserver(fao);
        monitor.start();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void stop() {
        try {
            monitor.stop();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StopWatcher.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old answer but an issue remains with `FileAlterationMonitor`.

Even if you call `FileAlterationMonitor#stop()`, the monitor won't stop until the `pollingInterval` delay has elapsed.

See : https://github.com/apache/commons-io/pull/58

An alternative to solve the issue is to set a small value for `pollingInterval`.